# get value from ng-repeat parent in a table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've got a table with a `ng-repeat` in the `th` tag. In the `tbody` I need to loop the values from the first `ng-repeat`. This is the table

```
<table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-ng-repeat="item in main.attributes['main:main'] | orderBy:'id':false track by $index" >
                        {{item.label}}
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td data-ng-repeat="data in item.values track by $index">
                        <span ng-if="(item.type | uppercase) == 'DATE' && data != '-'">{{data | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</span>
                        <span ng-if="(item.type | uppercase) == 'DATETIME' && data != '-'"> {{data | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</span>
                        <span ng-if="(item.type | uppercase) != 'DATETIME' && (item.type | uppercase) != 'DATE' && data != '-'"> {{data}}<span ng-if="!$last">,</span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

of course the `tbody` is not filled because i can't loop `item.values` being outside the first `ng-repeat`.

I've tried useing `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` but it doesn't show the entire table

Comment: Show example of input data and desired html output

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your need but I created an example 
[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/becher_henchiri/kbrx1mpn/1/) for you to look at. Here's the JS portion:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('TestController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.attributes = [{name:'Date'}];

      $scope.items = [
       {value:new Date('2018/02/22'),type:'date'},
       {value:new Date('2018/02/22 10:13:26'),type:'datetime'}
      ];
});
```